# How to add a time stamp to each line in java?

Tags: java, timestamp

I'm trying to write a code where each output from the code has a time stamp attached to it. I figured out how to add the time stamp once, but I need to have the time stamp attached to EACH line.

I imported "util.date", "util.calendar," and "sql.timestamp". And have already written the code to print out the time stamp once, but how to i put it in a method to repeat with every line????

here is the code i have written

```
java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();
System.out.println(new Timestamp(date.getTime());
```

Answer (score 2):

Write a `printTimeStamp` method and call it every time you print anything using `System.out.println()`

```
public static void printTimeStamp() {
    java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();
    System.out.println(new Timestamp(date.getTime());   
}
```

Comment: Nice! Answered 18 seconds before I did =P

Answer (score 2):

You can create a method and call it every time you print something out.

For example:

```
public static String ts() {
    return "Timestamp: " + new Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime());
}
```

And in every `println()` statement:

```
System.out.println(" ... text here ... " + ts());
```